# PHP using interfaces to browse multiple data source

Tags: symfony, interface

I am creating a Symphony application that browses different data sources.
the controller that I created knows too much about the data source but the application is designed in a way to not expect that.
The data source could be DB, JSON or XML.
is there any way to implement interfaces to do that? 
My controller knows the location of the XML file, and browse different data seperatly. I want to do it in one action.
That's my current controller ;

```
public function searchAction(Request $request) {

     if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
         $search_for = $request->get('search');
          //getting the searched products from the database
          $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TyreTyreBundle:Products');
          $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where("u.name LIKE '%".$search_for."%' or u.manufacturer LIKE '%".$search_for."%'")
            ->getQuery();
          $results = $query->getResult();

          //adding the XML file products
          $file_url = "bundles/tyretyre/xml/products.xml";
          //Convert the products.XML file into a SimpleXMLElement object
          $simpleXMLElementObject = simplexml_load_file($file_url);

          $i=0;
          //the array where will saved the searched products from the XML file
          $xml_result = [];
          //looping the xml object to find matching results
          while ($simpleXMLElementObject->product[$i]) {
              //first we will convert to lower case both searched item and the tested name
              if (strstr(strtolower($simpleXMLElementObject->product[$i]->name),strtolower($search_for))){
              //push that element into the array to display it later in the twig file
              array_push($xml_result, $simpleXMLElementObject->product[$i]);
              }
              $i++;
          }

          //end of products searching from the XML source

           //display the detail page with passing the DB result and XML result arrays
            return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:detail.html.twig', array('results' => $results,'xml_result' => $xml_result));
     }
     return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:search.html.twig');
}
```

My products entity :

```
namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Products
 */
class Products
{
//some getter and setters and private attribute
}
```

**EDIT** following VolCh solution,

I registered the service as following (I think I am doing it wrong) in /src/Tyre/TyreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml:

```
services:
  Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository:
     class: Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository

  Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface:
     class: Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\ProductRepositoryInterface
```

But then I get the following

> ContextErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: in
>   /home/smiles/Documents/tyre/src/Tyre/TyreBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php
>   line 56

Line 56: is this line :         `$serviceName = $repositoryMap[$request->get('db')];`

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- declare `\TyreTyreBundle\ProductRepository` interface (or `ProductDataSource` if you wish) with method `->search(string $needle): array` (or some DTO)
- implement it in DoctrinreProductRepository, XmlProductRepository, JsonProductRepository as service with constructor injection of \Doctrine\EntityRepository, xml-filename, json-filename
- get properly repository from container in actions
- (optional) create ProductRepositoryFactory whith createFor('db|xml|json') method and pass type to controller as part of route like '/datasource/{db|xml|json}' or request parameter like datasource?type=db'and create properly repository in one common action

**Added:**

Example (proof of concept, don't use, php7+):

src/TyreBundle/Repository/ProductRepositoryInterface.php

```php
namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository;

interface ProductRepositoryInterface
{
  function search(string $needle): array;
}
```

src/TyreBundle/Repository/DoctrineProductRepository.php

```
namespace Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository;

class DoctrineProductRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
  public function __constructor(EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function search(string $needle): array
  {
      $repository = $this->em->getRepository('TyreTyreBundle:Products');
      $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where("u.name LIKE '%".$needle."%' or u.manufacturer LIKE '%".$needle."%'")
        ->getQuery();
      return $query->getArrayResult();
  }
```

}

src/TyreBundle/Repository/XmlProductRepository.php
src/TyreBundle/Repository/JsonProductRepository.php

controller

```
public function searchAction(Request $request)
{
   $repositoryMap = [
     'db' => DoctrineProductRepository::class,
     'xml' => XmlProductRepository::class,
     'json' => JsonProductRepository::class,
   ];
   $serviceName = $repositoryMap[$request->get('type')];
   /** @var ProductRepositoryInterface */
   $repository = $this->get($serviceName);
   $results = $repository->search($request->get('serxh_for'));
   return $this->render('TyreTyreBundle:Default:detail.html.twig', array('results' => $results));
}
```

also you should register Repository classes as services with their names.

Comment: thank you, ut sounds more technical details for me, Im not that familiar with Symfony, would you mind to make more details where and how to put the interface ? and how to edit my Controller in this way ? Im thankful in advance

Comment: I think you are saving my life :) but I got an error, see my EDIT, ContextErrorException: Notice: Use of undefined constant DoctrineProductRepository - assumed 'DoctrineProductRepository' in /home/smiles/Documents/tyre/src/Tyre/TyreBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 51

Comment: Service name should be full class name like `Tyre\TyreBundle\Repository\DoctrineProductRepository`
and type in request should be one of 'db', 'xml', 'json'

Comment: could you please invite for a chat ?